# Show/hide disqus button don't work correctly with firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, disqus

I use disqus for my website and I've add a buton for showing/hiding comments. The button work fine on Chrome, Opera (and IE I guess) but fail on Firefox.

It fail because when I click on button, I don't show the div with comments. The div seems have no size. if I change window browser size … \°/ 
I see comments ! Why ?

```
<p id="commentsButton">
    <button id="buttonComment" onclick="toggleComments()">
        Commentaires</button>  
</p>
<script type="text/javascript">    
    function toggleComments(){
         if (document.getElementById("comments").style.display == "none"){           
            document.getElementById("comments").style.display="inline";
         } else {          
            document.getElementById("comments").style.display="none";
         }
     }  
</script>
```

It seems disqus ifame have style

```
style="height: 0px !important
```

What can'I do ?

Answer (score 1):

Firefox (and some versions of IE) have quirky behavior when Disqus is loaded in a hidden element. You can fix this by wrapping the Disqus embed code inside of your `toggleComments()` function so that it loads when that element is visible.

Make sure you leave the configuration variables, such as `disqus_shortname` outside of the function, however. All together it can look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
var disqus_shortname='YOUR_SHORTNAME';

function toggleComments(){
    if (document.getElementById("comments").style.display == "none"){           
        document.getElementById("comments").style.display="inline";

        (function() {
            var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
            dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
            (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
        } 
        else {          
            document.getElementById("comments").style.display="none";
        }
    }
}   
</script>
```

Comment: Don't work for me :-(
I add ");" before } but nothing append. 
You say "disqus loaded in hidden element". I load page with "comments inline" and, before end of page, I call "toggleComments" for hiding comments div immediately …